# Make a long int easier to read

Tags: c#

I'm working on a fairly simple console application but I got one little problem. It's very hard to read large numbers unless you go close to the monitor and look very carefully. It's very important that the user immediately can see how much it is. For example, which of these is the easiest to read?

```
143000532
143.000.532
```

I want it to look like the second one. It's fairly simple to just do an if every time I need to print a large number but that's tedious and makes the code look bad. Is there any way I can do this in a beautiful way and still be able to use the variable in calculations and comparisons?

Comment: May be write a function to display number which takes the number in input

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int intValue = 123456789;
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and you will get 123,456,789.00

edit:
if you want to eliminate the decimal point use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: And of course, by using a culture that uses the "." thousands separator, we will get the format that the OP wants.

Comment: The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: use: `using System.Globalization;` and a quick trick. when you paste this line just click on culture.info and hit `ctrl + .` and this will suggest you to use the apropriate namespace... This works for all clases you have references on

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Format("{0:n}", 143000532);
```

Will result in 143,000,532.0

Or if you don't want decimals...

```
string.Format("{0:n0}", 143000532);
```

Will result in 143,000,532